# How to change query params value in spring cloud gateway custom written GlobalFilter

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I have configured spring cloud gateway in my spring boot project. My requirement is that, i want to change query params values in Custom written org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GlobalFilter .

e.g postman request - http://localhost:8080/employee/message?q1=**abc**&q2=**123**

expected filter redirection - http://localhost:8080/employee/message?q1=**xyz**&q2=**789**

so that, my controller will get q1 value as **xyz** and q2 value as **789** instead the original values.
So i want to change the value of my query params as per business case.
I am able to get the query params in my filter but not able to figure out exactly how to change them.

Following is my custom filter

```
@Component
public class PreFilter implements GlobalFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        
                ServerWebExchange modExchange = changeQueryParams(exchange);
                    return chain.filter(modExchange);
    }
    
    private static ServerWebExchange changeQueryParams(ServerWebExchange exchange)  {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("q1", Arrays.asList("xyz"));
        map.put("q2", Arrays.asList("789"));
        MultiValueMap<String, String> newMultiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(map);
        
        Builder builder = request.mutate();
        request = builder.uri(UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(exchange.getRequest()
                .getURI())
              .replaceQueryParams(newMultiValueMap)
              .build()
              .toUri()).build();

        ServerWebExchange modifiedExchange = exchange.mutate().request(request).build();
        return modifiedExchange;
    }
}
```

Spring boot version = 2.7.0

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. So will give my workaround.

The issue lies in the `org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter` that writes the URI to the `exchange` attributes *before* any global filters run.

So you can either do your rewriting in a `GatewayFilter`, that then needs to be defined on every route, or in a *hack* along the lines of (Code in Kotlin, not Java):

```
val attributeUrl = exchange.attributes[ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR] as URI
val newUri = updateUriQueryParameters(attributeUrl)
exchange.attributes[ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR] = newUri
```

We have many routes in our gateway so I went with the later.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. We have an answer for Kotlin.

For Java:

```
exchange.getAttributes().put(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, mutatedRequest.getURI());
```

Where `mutatedRequest.getURI()` is your URI with query params included. Working example in [this repository](https://github.com/UnirCs/back-end-cloud-gateway-filters).